# How can I remove iOS 4.2 from an iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios

I need to remove iOS 4.2 beta from an iPad which I added using iTunes and the option+click Restore button feature.

When I click "Restore" in iTunes I get an error (image attached). I have the iOS SDK & XCode installed.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1:** You need to put the iPad into recovery mode.

*Press and hold the home and sleep/wake buttons until the device shuts off. Keep holding the home key until the "connect to iTunes" graphic appears on the screen.*

**Step 2:** Make sure you have iOS 3.2 somewhere on your system. Drag it into the organizer.

*You can get [any version of the iOS firmware from here](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/).*

**Step 3:** Open XCode's organizer and connect the iPad.

**Step 4:** Select your iPad in the organizer and choose the firmware version on the top right.

---

**NOTE:** You can probably use replace steps 3 and 4 with Option + Click in iTunes, just make sure to have the proper firmware lying around on your system.

**NOTE2:** Excuse me, I meant iOS 3.2, not iOS 4.1. I'm a little distracted at the moment.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Only up votes! Great answer.

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com - Thanks, someone did downvote though. (Click on the number of votes and you'll see the ratio.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have iOS 3.2 because that's the only other iOS version that supports iPad. Follow the steps Moshe posted.